# How reference correctly images through many .adoc files located in different folders

Tags: atom-editor, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am working with Atom Editor + the two plugins/packages available about asciidoctor.

- asciidoc-preview
- language-asciidoc

All work how it is expected. But I am with the following situation:

I have the following directory structure:

```
xml
  figures
     findOneXml.adoc
     findOneXml.png
  urls
     findOne.adoc
```

Where `findOneXml.adoc` (within *figures* folder) has

```
[[findOneXml]]
image::findOneXml.png[caption="Figure - " title="findOneXml"]
```

With the live preview I can see the image and its respective description

Now with `findOne.adoc` (within *url* folder) contains among many things the following line:

```
include::../figures/findOneXml.adoc[]
```

I think the path reference is ok. if I use other, the live preview shows an error message about an invalid or wrong path.

But through the live preview I see broken the image but I can see the description.

[image]

What is wrong or missing?

Even with `include::./../figures/findOneXml.adoc[]` fails

**Note**: in the sub/child document I need add other data how notes, tips (Admonition), that child document would be reused many times by other parents. So I only don't need refer to the image only.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The image is resolved relative to an internal base path of the asciidoc rendering engine. In your case I assume the engine takes the path of the rendered (main, parent) document. So, images are resolved relative to that. Try:

```
image::../figures/findOneXml.png[]
```

This should work for both adoc documents, as the path moves up to the parent directory  and then explicitly down into the figures directory.

In case you want to have a common absolute base for images, you can also set the `:imagesdir:` attribute to the base url of your images directory. This should then also work with live previews:

- [Asciidoctor Documentation Site - Set the Images Directory](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/macros/images-directory/#imagesdir-attribute-syntax)
- [Asciidoctor Documentation Site -
  Image Paths and Formats](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/pdf-converter/latest/image-paths-and-formats/#imagesdir)

Comment: Hello, thanks by the reply. Even when that works (not tested yet) in the sub/child document I need add other data how notes, tips (Admonition), that child document would be reused many times by other parents. So I only don't need refer to the image only.

Comment: When running asciidoctor (not sure about the plugins, if they make this option available or not) you'll want to set the root directory to some parent folder then adjust the references as needed, in your example I'd say use `xml` as the parent directory.

Comment: Added more info to my answer to make you aware of the :imagesdir: attribute.

Comment: @ManuelJordan I suspect now that you misunderstood my answer. I suggested that you add that image::../figures/findOneXml.png[] reference to your SUB/CHILD document. I do not suggest that you directly reference the image from your parent document.

Comment: Thanks a lot, with `:imagesdir:` works perfect now. About your latest answer, the figure.png is in the same location than the sub-child document

Comment: Hi @MartinSchimak just curious if exists a way that `:imagesdir: adocs/results/figures` works for subfolders of `figures` too.

Comment: @ManuelJordan Once you have set the :imagesdir: folder it affects all image::* references, even with subfolders - so in case you need to reference an image in a  subfolder of :imagesdir:, just use e.g. image::sub/findTwoXml.png

Comment: @ManuelJordan I still think you misunderstand the first part of my answer. As long as your parent documents are on the same "depth" of your folder hierarchy as the included figures/findOneXml.adoc (regardless of the specific folder!), you can use image::../figures/findOneXml.png[] within figures/findOneXml.adoc and your parent documents (which include findOneXml.adoc) will successfully show the images, because the path ../figures/findOneXml.png is fully valid for them, too. In this case you don't need the :imagesdir: - it all depends on your very specific requirements...

Comment: Thanks @MartinSchimak by the clarification. Really appreciate your support.

Comment: According your two latest comments, seems more cleaner and less verbose use `:imagesdir:` . Thanks a lot! It avoids use "../" and therefore I am able to change any .adoc in the structure of my directories.

Comment: See also the comment at https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/1567. (I wish we could assemble asciidoc hierarchically, not just by simple preprocessor.)